# How to searching part of object inside array list without looping method

Tags: vb.net, search, arraylist

I save the client data into an array list. How to find part of data(currentIP) inside the array list(clientList) with fast method ?

Code as follow:

```
' Array list to keep Clients Object
Protected Friend clientList As ArrayList = ArrayList.Synchronized(New ArrayList())

Public Class Clients
    public clientIPAdrress As IPAddress
    public clientTCP As TcpClient
    public clientStream As SslStream
End Class


Public Sub Test()

  ' Create objClients Object from Clients Class
  Dim objClients as new Clients 

  ' Add objClients to Array List  
  clientList.Add(objClients)

  Dim currentIP as IPAdress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.2")
  Dim isIPFound as Boolean = False

  ' Search currentIP inside clientList with looping method
  For Each ip As Clients In clientList                                                                              
     If ip.ClientIPAdrress = currentIP Then
        isIPFound = True
        Exit For
     End If
  Next

End Sub
```

Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a typed `List(Of Clients)` instead, then cou can use LINQ:

```
Dim clientList As New List(Of Clients)
clientList.Add(new Clients())
Dim isIPFound=clientList.Any(Function(ip) ip.ClientIPAdrress = currentIP)
```

But essentially it is the same as your loop just in one row.

If you need to find the fastest way, you could sort your list and [BinarySearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ba2bttb.aspx) the IP with a custom comparer. Or, if the IP is unique in the list, you could use a `Dictionary(Of IPAdress,Clients)` instead.